# My macbook pro crashes after logging in

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

one week ago my macbook pro from 2011 crashed while doing stuff on a virtual machine (VMWare Fusion).

[[image: MacBook Hardware1]

I don't think it has something to do with it. Since that incident I could restart the macbook but it would crash while loading or I could get it on but then it would always crash afterwards (2-30 mins).

[image]

Before it crashes it can look like this image above. The screen seems to be displaced.. I already pressed options+cmd+p+r while starting and checked if I'd found something stressing the CPU or memory. So it's sadly unusable right now. I don't remember that I have had any issues before! Thank you.

Comment: I want to add that when the screen is getting displaced it can get blurred too! And that I talked to a Apple worker and he told me to do a diagnose  but that caused the error dec500 which means that it couldn't diagnosed any problem at all!

Comment: you can see the details of the crash if you type "cat /var/log/system.log" in a terminal...